# include multiple js files using Ti.include function

Tags: titanium

I can include 1 js file with Ti.include like:

```
Ti.include("login.js")
```

But, i am having problem with including multiple js files.
As a work around, i write Ti.include multiple times, which is less readable.

Any idea, how to achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Tweetanium](https://github.com/appcelerator/tweetanium/blob/master/mobile/Tweetanium/Resources/tweetanium/tweetanium.js) does it like so:

```
Ti.include(
    '/tweetanium/ui/ui.js',
    '/tweetanium/model/model.js',
    '/tweetanium/config/config.js'
);
```

Comment: This method is deprecated http://www.tidev.io/2014/05/30/sdk-3-3-0-ti-include-deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

Generally we should avoid including js file. It will hamper performance. You can have common js functionality to call any function defined in other files..

Answer (score 0):

var All = require('ui/common/All');

```
    Tree = require('ui/common/Tree');
    EBOM = require('ui/common/E-BOM');
    MBOM = require('ui/common/M-BOM');
    SBOM = require('ui/common/S-BOM');
```